# Что такое вызов метода, переопределенного в наследнике, по интерфейсу родительского класса?

Tags: наследование, полиморфизм, объекты, ооп

Я считаю, что **полиморфизм**. Но в тесте правильным ответом помечена **инкапсуляция**. Есть еще вариант **наследование**. Я прав или я чего-то недопонимаю?

Comment: Очередная засада для читателя кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Соглашусь с Вами, что это полиморфизм.

Answer (score 0):

Это полиморфизм.
Хотя, справедливости ради стоит отметить, что если бы вопрс был о переопределенном методе интерфейса, то инкапсуляцию можно было бы оправдать в качестве ответа. Т.к. скрытую за интерфейсом конкретную реализацию также рассматривают как пример инкапсуляции.